# WSO2 EI - retrieving property set inside script

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to retrieve a property set inside a script mediator for later use, however it seems to be blank. This is my code:

```js
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var log = mc.getServiceLog();
var payload = mc.getPayloadXML();

var numDevices5GHz = payload["Device.WiFi.AccessPoint.10101.AssociatedDeviceNumberOfEntries"];
log.info("numDevices5GHz :"+numDevices5GHz);
  var devices5GHz = new Array(numDevices5GHz);
//formats 5GHz associated devices parameters
for(i = 0; i<numDevices5GHz; i++){
 var device = new Object();
   device.name="nome"+i;
   device.value=i;
   devices5GHz[i] = device;
 }

mc.setProperty("devices5GHz",devices5GHz);
]]></script>
<log>
    <property expression="get-property('devices5GHz')" name="DEVICES 5GHz"/>
</log>
```

and this is the result:

```
[2020-03-31 12:11:30,223] [EI-Core]  INFO - CommonScriptMessageContext numDevices5GHz :1
[2020-03-31 12:11:30,224] [EI-Core]  INFO - CommonScriptMessageContext name: nome0, value: 0
[2020-03-31 12:11:30,224] [EI-Core]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:44561262-94fa-4d92-99f0-d5a25e0d28bd, Direction: response, DEVICES 5GHz =
```

So, I can see that inside the script the devices5GHz Array has one member (this will later be populated with real data), but when I try to retrieve it outside the script it's empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the javascript array object you are assigning inside the Script mediator, cannot be read by the Property mediator. If you can create an appropriate string inside the Script mediator and assign, then it would become accessible outside the Script mediator.

Comment: Yes, eventually I realised that I'd have to serialize the object to be able to use it outside the script. Thanks anyway Arunan.